Regex not extracting CNIC details correctly from text extracted through EasyOCR in Python
I'm trying to extract personal details (such as name, gender, date of birth, etc.) from an image of a CNIC (Computerized National Identity Card) using EasyOCR and regex in Python.
I try to fetch the relevant data through regex. Some fields, like date of birth, gender and country of stay, aren't extracted correctly.
Problem: I have a CNIC image from which I use EasyOCR to extract text. I use regular expressions to capture fields like CNIC number, name, gender, etc. However, I am getting incorrect or missing output for some fields.
I wanted the output to be a notepad file in which Cnic number and rest of other fields are written..
Here is the code;
import easyocr

txt = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
text = txt.readtext(image_path)
# Join OCR detected text into a single string and clean it up
etext = " ".join([item[1] for item in text])
print("Cleaned Extracted Text:\n", etext)  # Debugging the cleaned text


# Use regular expressions to extract relevant data
cnic_data = {}

# Regular expressions for extracting CNIC number, name, father name, dob  etc.
cnic_number_pattern = r'(\d{5}-\d{7}-\d{1})'
name_pattern = r'Name\s*\s*([A-Za-z\s]+)'
father_name_pattern = r'Father\s*Name\s*[:\-\s]*([A-Za-z\s]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z\s]+)*)'

gender_pattern = r'Gender\s*[:\-\s]*(?:M|F|Male|Female)'

dob_pattern = r'Date\s*of\s*Birth\s*[:\-\s]*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})'                 country_of_stay_pattern = r'Country\s*of\s*Stay\s*[:\-\s]*([A-Za-z\s]+)'


# If a match is found, save it, otherwise mark it as not found

cnic_data['CNIC Number'] = re.search(cnic_number_pattern, etext)
cnic_data['Name'] = re.search(name_pattern, etext)
cnic_data['Father Name'] = re.search(father_name_pattern, etext)
cnic_data['Gender'] = re.search(gender_pattern, etext)
cnic_data['Date of Birth'] = re.search(dob_pattern, etext)
cnic_data['Country of Stay'] = re.search(country_of_stay_pattern, etext)


# Extracting the values from regex matches
cnic_data = {key: (match.group(1) if match else "Not Found") for key, match in cnic_data.items()}

with open(file_path, 'w') as f:

  for key, value in cnic_data.items():
    
    f.write(f"{key}: {value}\n")
print(f"Data has been written to {file_path}")
    

Wanted Output:
I expect the output to be a Notepad file with properly extracted CNIC details like:
CNIC Number: 37403-9637109-9
Name: Muhammad Talha Bin Maghfoor 
Father Name: Maghfoor Ahmed
Gender: M
Date of Birth: 11.01.1999
Country of Stay: Pakistan


The  gender date of birth and country of stay fields aren't being extracted correctly (or sometimes not at all).
What I've tried:

I have ensured that the field names in the regex patterns (e.g Name, Father Name, date of birth ,Gender, Country of Stay) match what appears in the text extracted from the CNIC image.

I've tried adjusting the regex patterns, but the issue persists.


I've tried updating the regex patterns for Father Name , gender and date of birth, but I am still not able to extract them correctly.
Can someone help me debug the issue or suggest any improvements to the regex patterns?
Input: The input is a Cnic image
Here is the output:
Actual output:
PAKISTAN National Identity Card  ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF PAKISTAN Name Muhammad Talha Bin Maghfoor  Father Name Maghfoor Ahmed Gender Country of Stay M Pakistan Identity Number Date of Birth 37403-9637109-9 11.01.1999  Date of Issue Date of Expiry 03.02.2024 03.02.2034


CNIC Number: 37403-9637109-9
Name: Muhammad Talha Bin Maghfoor 
Father Name: Maghfoor Ahmed Gender Country of Stay M Pakistan Identity Number Date of Birth 
Gender: Not Found
Date of Birth: Not Found
Country of Stay: M Pakistan Identity Number Date of Birth 

Data has been written to cnic_data.txt


You could write patterns for all of those parts that you want to get, but the data looks mixed. So it would work for this example, but if the OCR produces another order of the mixed data, chances are that the patterns do not work any more. Did you encounter more different mixes of the "Actual output:" ?

See this Python example

Yes i encounter different mixes and as well some times the ocr do not extract correct data. i want a generic solution.

Yes but there is no generic solution if the data can have multiple random formats

If you want a solution allowing multiple formats, you need to include all possible formats in your question. You asked about creating regexes for that specific input.

It depends on the OCR extraction; if the OCR extracts text correctly, then it will match each format in the regex.

Didn't you say the issue was the regex part (and you are asking about regexes) and not the OCR extraction part (and that the extracted text is ok)? If you are asking about regexes, you need to be very clear about what should and shouldn't match.

I understand, but when I tried using other CNIC images, they weren't extracted correctly, which is why the regex didn't capture the fields properly. Could you kindly correct this?

We cannot correct anything without knowing all possible inputs.
